# A conditinal probability problem I can't figure out

Tags: probability

Suppose ancient Romans had a $0.2$ chance of dying in each of the following age intervals: $[0, 2], [2, 10], [10, 30], [30, 70]$ and $[70, 90]$.

To keep calculations straightforward, let's assume that, conditional on dying in any one of those five buckets, age at death was uniformly distributed across the interval. That means that, conditional on dying between age $0$ and $2$, the average Roman lived to be $1$ year old; conditional on dying between age $2$ and $10$, the average was $6$ years; et cetera. Under these (fictitious) numbers, life expectancy at birth was only $31.4$ years, due largely to child mortality.

What was the life expectancy (i.e. expected age at death) of an ancient Roman who was still alive at age $30$? It's much more than $31.4$ years — can you figure out why?

Comment: Yes.  Use the Law of Total Expectation; also known as the Tower Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a Roman was still alive at age $30$, then he will die either in the range $[30,70]$ (so on average, at $50$) or the range $[70,90]$ (so on average, at $80$).

> These are equally likely, so the overall average is halfway between $50$ and $80$.

Answer (score 0):

If your fictitious Roman is still alive at age 30 it will die in one of the next two intervals with equal probability.   Apply the Law of Total Probability to determine the conditional life expectancy.

> $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(L\mid L>30) ~&=~ {\mathsf E(L\mid L\in [30; 70])\,\mathsf P(L\in [30;70]\mid L>30) \\ +\mathsf E(L\mid L\in [70;90])\,\mathsf P(L\in[70;90]\mid L>30)}\end{align}$$